# $\lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac{\sec^2{x}}{x^2} - \cot^2{x}\right)$

Tags: limits

May I ask what's wrong with my process? Why is this answer different from wolfram's?
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac{\sec^2{x}}{x^2} - \cot^2{x}\right) &= \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin^2x-\cos^4 x·x^2}{x^2·\cos^2 x·\sin^2x} \\
  &= \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin^2x-\cos^4 x·x^2}{x^4} \\
  &= \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin^2x}{x^4} -\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\cos^4 x·x^2}{x^4} \\
  &= \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{x^2} -\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\cos^4 x}{x^2} \\
  &= \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1-\cos^4 x}{x^2}  \\
  &= \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{4\cos^3x·\sin x}{2x}  \\
  &= \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{4\cos^3x}{2}  \\
  &=  2
\end{align*}

[image]

Comment: You have several non-existent limits. $\lim [f(x)-g(x)]=\lim f(x)-\lim g(x)$ if **both the limits exist and are finite**.

Comment: I don't think you included the $\cot^2 x$ in the wolfram input, which would obviously lead to the divergent result. Check this https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Limit%5BSec%5Bx%5D%5E2%2Fx%5E2+-+Cot%5Bx%5D%5E2%2C+x+-%3E+0%5D.

Comment: hao, actually wolframalpha gives the correct result. See [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2eEO.jpg).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution by using the following two well-known limits :

$\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sin x}x=1\;\;,\quad\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{x-\sin x}{x^3}=\dfrac16\;.$

It results that

$\dfrac{\sec^2\!x}{x^2}-\cot^2\!x=\dfrac{\sin^2\!x-x^2\cos^4\!x}{x^2\sin^2\!x\cos^2\!x}=\\[12pt]=\dfrac x{\sin x\cos^2\!x}\!\cdot\!\dfrac{\sin x+x\cos^2\!x}{\sin x}\!\cdot\!\dfrac{\sin x-x\cos^2\!x}{x^3}=\\[12pt]=\dfrac x{\sin x\cos^2\!x}\!\cdot\!\dfrac{\sin x+x\cos^2\!x}{\sin x}\!\cdot\!\dfrac{\sin x-x+x\sin^2\!x}{x^3}=\\[12pt]=\dfrac x{\sin x\cos^2\!x}\!\cdot\!\left(1+\dfrac{x\cos^2\!x}{\sin x}\right)\!\cdot\!\left(\dfrac{\sin^2\!x}{x^2}-\dfrac{x-\sin x}{x^3}\right)$

for any $\;x\in\left]-\dfrac\pi2,\dfrac\pi2\right[\setminus\big\{0\big\}\,.$

Since $\,\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sin x}x=1\,$ and $\,\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{x-\sin x}{x^3}=\dfrac16\,,\,$ it follows that

$\lim\limits_{x\to0}\left(\dfrac{\sec^2\!x}{x^2}-\cot^2\!x\right)=\\[12pt]=\lim\limits_{x\to0}\left[\dfrac x{\sin x\cos^2\!x}\!\cdot\!\left(\!1+\dfrac{x\cos^2\!x}{\sin x}\!\right)\!\cdot\!\left(\!\dfrac{\sin^2\!x}{x^2}-\dfrac{x\!-\!\sin x}{x^3}\!\right)\right]\!=\\[12pt]=1\!\cdot\!\big(1+1\big)\!\cdot\!\left(1-\dfrac16\right)=\dfrac53\,.$

Answer (score 5):

By Taylor's formula,
$$\sec^2 x=\left(1+\frac{x^2}{2}+O(x^3)\right)^2=1+x^2+O(x^3)$$
$$\cot^2 x=\frac{\cos^2 x}{\sin^2x}=\left(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{x}{3}+O(x^3)\right)^2=\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{2}{3}+O(x^2)$$
both as $x\to0$, hence,
$$\frac{\sec^2 x}{x^2}-\cot^2 x=\frac{5}{3}+O(x^2)$$
as $x\to0$. The limit is $5/3$.

Comment: If you use big-O, you should write $=$ instead of $\sim$.

Comment: @Gary. You are right, for my final expression I will change to $=$. For the $\cot^2 x$ expansion, I would keep it as there is the divergent $1/x^2$ term. Is that correct?

Comment: @Gary. Or should I refrain from using $\sim$ notation when I keep an explicit big-O term.

Comment: The divergent part doesn't change anything. With the error term you have an equality.

Comment: @Gary. Makes sense. It's either I choose to use big-O and state equality, or drop the error term and state equality in the asymptotic sense $\sim$.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is wrong from the start, since we actually have$$\frac{\sec^2x}{x^2}-\cot^2(x)=\frac{\sin^2(x)-x^2\cos^{\color{red}4}(x)}{x^2\cos^2(x)\sin^2(x)}.$$Besides, as you were told in the comments, the equality$$\lim_{x\to a}(f(x)-g(x))=\lim_{x\to a}f(x)-\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$$holds if the limits $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$ exist in $\Bbb R$.

Finally, the limit is neither $\infty$ nor $0$; it is $\dfrac53$.

Comment: Thanx, I got it.